# How to check the value from EditText if the value contains 3 string separated with comma?

Tags: java, android, xml

I create a program on Android Studio, where i have an EditText in which the user can enter 3 numbers separated with comma, and each number must be between 10 and 15 digits, representing a phone number.
Here is the method that verify if the EditText has min 10 and max 15 numbers which works fine:

```
private boolean validateNumberField(EditText editText){

    if(editText.getText().toString().length()<10 || editText.getText().toString().length()>15){
        editText.setError(" The number field should have minimum 10 digits and a maximum of 15");
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The qestion is: Is there a way to verify if each numbers contains min 10 and max 15 digits?
Thank you.

Comment: [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) in Java: `str.matches("\\d{10,15},\\d{10,15},\\d{10,15}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean validateNumberField(EditText editText){

    String entry = editText.getText().toString();

    String [] phoneNumbers = entry.split(","); // Seperate string on commas

    for(String phone : phoneNumbers){
        if( !hasCorrectDigitNumber(phone) ) {
            // Toast maybe?
            editText.setError(" The number field should have minimum 10 digits and a maximum of 15");
            return false;
        } 
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean hasCorrectDigitNumber(String phone){
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++){
        char c = phone.charAt(i); 
        if(c <= '9' && c >= '0')
            count++;
    }

    return count >= 10 && count <= 15;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works very well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Surely this can be best done with RegEx.

But in your case, splitting the string might do the trick because this is nothing too complicated:

```
String string = editText.getText().toString();
String[] parts = string.split(",");
//now just check for each part if the condition is met
foreach ( String part : parts){
    if (part.length()<10 || part.length()>15){  
        editText.setError("whatever");
        return;
    }
}
//if you get to this part, there's no error, everything went fine
//so do whatever you need if there's no error
//or simply return true
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  String[]arr= editText.getText().toString().split(",");

  boolean valid=false;
  for (String a  : arr) {
     if(validate(a))
     {
     valid=true;
     }
      else
     {
     valid=false;
     break;
     }
  }
if (valid)
{
// valid number
}
else
{
//not valid number
}
```

and use function bellow:

```
  private boolean validate(String txt){

    if(txt.length()<10 || txt.length()>15){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: my idea exactly! Wrote the code and posted, then saw your answer resembles mine.. Also wanted to use a private function to validate, but didn't write it :D Also, you don't need `else`, just write `return true;`, because it'll already have returned from the function if you entered the `if` branch.

Comment: sorry i was writting that you posted your answer, sorry i did not see your answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, i didn't see yours either :) I don't mind, they're both good answers, so +1 from me :D